# Morphia does not recognize my @ID annotated field

Tags: mongodb, scala, morphia

I have a simple POSO `GroupACLTemplate` which I want to persist. It is subclassed from an abstract class. I have annotated it with `@Entity` and also have an `@Id`

```
@Entity("aclTemplate")
@SerialVersionUID(1L)
class GroupACLTemplate(@(Id@field) id: String, groupRoleAccess: Set[GroupRoleAccess]) extends AclTemplate(id) with Serializable
```

When I deploy my war, I am not seeing any collection of `GroupACLTemplate`. I also tried this

```
class GroupACLTemplate(@Id id: String, groupRoleAccess: Set[GroupRoleAccess]) extends AclTemplate(id) with Serializable
```

I added a test case and tried saving an object like this

```
@Inject
var aclTemplateRepository: AclTemplateRepository = _
aclTemplateRepository.save(aclTemplate.head)
```

The error says

```
NoId complained about com.java.sample.acl.GroupACLTemplate. : No field is annotated with @Id; but it is required
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While declaring constructor params, Scala maps those to `private final` variables if we do not use any modifier. However if `var` is added, they are mapped to `private` variables. That is the change I did. Now the class declaration looks like

```
@Entity("aclTemplate")
@SerialVersionUID(1L)
class GroupACLTemplate(@(Id@field) var id: String, groupRoleAccess: Set[GroupRoleAccess]) extends AclTemplate(id) with Serializable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you file an issue in [github](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/issues), I can take a look.  Morphia works with class files so everything should "just work" but we're not currently testing against scala classes so perhaps there's something odd about how scala compiles down to bytecode that's throwing off the mapper.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try to get something for you soon.

Answer (score -1):

you should use the Id from morphia instead of the one from spring data